# Deploying multiple angular single page applications on Azure App service

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy two Angular applications to an app service plan where one of the application is accessible through baseurl and another is accessible through baseurl/app1

I was able to get it to work using virtual directory path mapping. But the problem is that angular deep routes are not accessible when I try to do baseurl/app1/route.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular routing to checkout" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^app1/.*"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/app1/" appendQueryString="true"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I need a way to let the angular application handle the internal routing for /app1/route.

Answer (score 0):

This `web.config` works for me:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="app2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app2/.*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/app2/" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="app" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".js" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
      </profiles>
    </caching>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Inside my appService it looks like that:

```
-- wwwroot // angular build of main app
-- wwwroot_app2 // angular build of second app available on /app2
```

I keep `web.config` inside `wwwroot`. If I remember correctly, it was important to have only one `web.config` file inside appService.
Remember also to setup correctly `baseHref` and `deployUrl` in second app.